# Notation seen in "awfully sophisticated proof..." I don't understand

Tags: soft-question, notation

I want to understand what the definition of $f_n$ given [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/44742/75082) means? I tried to seek on the net but I not succeeded. I precise I do chemistry, maths are "just" a curiosity for me.

I should be glad, thanks

Comment: For a set $A$, the notation $1_A$ is used for the indicator function of $A$, or the characteristic function of $A$. Another common notation is $\chi_A$. It's defined by $$1_A(x) = \chi_A(x) = \begin{cases} 1 &, x \in A \\ 0 &, x \notin A.\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1_{[0,n]}$ is the function defined on the interval $[0,n]$ which takes the constant value $1.$ Hence $\frac{1}{n}1_{[0,n]}$ is the function defined on the interval $[0,n]$ which takes the constant value $1/n.$

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, we wish to view each $f_n$ as a function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ and so we define $f_n(x) = 0$ when $x$ is outside the interval $[0,n].$

Comment: Hum ok so $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{x}$?

Comment: @Shadock No, it is not. $f_n$ denotes a piecewise constant function. It evaluates $1/n$ on $[0,n]$ and $0$ outside.

Comment: Actually $f_n$ is not a function defined on $[0,n]$ but on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: No. If $x \in [0,n]$: $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n}\left( \mathbf{1}_{[0,n]}(x) \right) =  \frac{1}{n} \, 1 = \frac{1}{n}$, otherwise $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n} \, 0 = 0$.

Comment: Hum ok thank you I understood ! :)

Answer (score 2):

$f_n:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is prescribed by $x\mapsto\frac1{n}$ if $x\in[0,n]$ and $x\mapsto0$ otherwise. This for $n\in\mathbb Z_{>0}$.

The function is the same as $\frac1{n}1_{[0,n]}$ where $1_{[0,n]}$ is the characteristic function of set $[0,n]\subset\mathbb R$.

Its codomain is less strict. You can also take e.g. $[0,\infty)$.